# RecyclerView with grid

Tags: android, grid, android-recyclerview

Managed to set a basic listview using this widget but I have not found any method to change the layout or display to a grid.

Over the Google I/O 2014 they mentioned several times that RecyclerView could replace gridview as well as listview. The sample and sources for recyclerView in the L preview don't point to anything related to a grid.

How to make the recycler act like a grid?

Comment: show what you have tried so far.

Comment: just used the tutorial from https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html

Comment: AFAIK, there is no stock layout manager that offers a grid with `RecyclerView`, at least at the present time.

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened. A good answer won't be broad  or long, it would simply state how to setup a layout manager that will show a grid using the new recycler view or point to an available sample.

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Comment: The closest thing I can find: https://github.com/antoniolg/RecyclerViewExtensions I've looked at the built in linear version and it's quite complicated actually...

Comment: @NightlyNexus no one needs such library nowadays when there is an official `RecyclerView`

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev TwoWayView is based on RecyclerView.  Also, Mr. Rocha is going to release an API for it, so it will be easier to write custom, powerful LayoutManagers.

Comment: @NightlyNexus ah, sorry - it didn't noticed that it is based on `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Tom91136 wins the prize, that is the closest thing to a gridview working on recyclerView. Thanks man

Comment: You can simply initialize the recycler view with GridLayoutManager instead of LinearLayoutManager!! Thats it!!  mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,4);

Comment: @Abhinava that's an awesome solution. works like a charm!